# Is there any possibility to Deploy Single Report in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

I'm having problem with SSRS Report Deployment. I've 2 Hundreds of Reports in my SSRS Report Solution. When, I deploy the Report it deploy all reports which is very time consuming. 
Now, what I'm looking for is, I want to re-deploy only the Report I've changed recently.

In BIDS, I didn't found anything to support the feature I'm looking for.

So, If there is any possibility to Deploy a Single Report?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can just deploy a single report by right clicking on the report itself and selecting **Deploy**:

[image]

One thing to note is that it will **also** try to deploy any Shared Data Source the report references.

However, if the project level property **OverwriteDataSources** is set to *False* this won't affect any Data Source that was deployed previously.

[image]